# Compiling from source is building wrong version

Tags: compiling

I'm a little confused right now, but I'm trying to compile libtiff-tools version 4.0.6 on Ubuntu 14.04 but it keeps compiling and installing the same version that is available in the repos (4.0.3, not 4.0.6). I downloaded the source for version 4.0.6 from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tiff/4.0.6-1.

On a system without libtiff-tools installed, I download the source, unpack it then:

```
# ./configure
[bunch of messages]
Libtiff is now configured for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

Installation directory:             /usr/local
Documentation directory:            ${prefix}/share/doc/tiff-4.0.6
C compiler:                         gcc -g -O2 -Wall -W
C++ compiler:                       g++ -g -O2
Enable runtime linker paths:        no
Enable linker symbol versioning:    no
Support Microsoft Document Imaging: yes
Use win32 IO:                       no

Support for internal codecs:
CCITT Group 3 & 4 algorithms:       yes
Macintosh PackBits algorithm:       yes
LZW algorithm:                      yes
ThunderScan 4-bit RLE algorithm:    yes
NeXT 2-bit RLE algorithm:           yes
LogLuv high dynamic range encoding: yes

Support for external codecs:
ZLIB support:                       no
Pixar log-format algorithm:         no
JPEG support:                       no
Old JPEG support:                   no
JPEG 8/12 bit dual mode:            no
ISO JBIG support:                   no
LZMA2 support:                      no

C++ support:                        yes

OpenGL support:                     no
```

Okay, missing some support for some stuff, but moving on:

```
make
[more messages]

make install
[more messages]
```

Then when I invoke:

```
/usr/local/bin/tiff2pdf
```

I get:

```
LIBTIFF, Version 4.0.3
Copyright (c) 1988-1996 Sam Leffler
Copyright (c) 1991-1996 Silicon Graphics, Inc.
```

What gives?

Comment: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/new/library/dir /usr/local/bin/tiff2pdf` ?

Comment: So I'm missing the necessary shared libraries for it to install 4.0.6? But shouldn't that come up in the compile process? I grabbed the same source files and compiled them on a 16.04 system and the version was 4.0.6.

Comment: No, no. If you compile a new library and want your new library to be used by a program you need to call the program setting `LD_LIRBRARY_PATH` to the directory where you put your new library. Otherwise it will load the system-supplied libraries.

Comment: Bear with me since I don't compile that often. `/usr/local/bin/tiff2pdf` is the program installed by the make/make install process. So when I run that, it's the binary that's the result of `make install`. During make install it says `Libraries have been installed in:
   /usr/local/lib` so shouldn't that be the default library it calls when running the program?

Comment: Try `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib /usr/local/bin/tiff2pdf`. Please also show `ls /usr/local/lib`.

Comment: Okay, that works. So, noob question, how do I get the program to default to that library path without invoking it using LD_LIBRARY_PATH?